# CakePHP-2.0: return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); where is this redirect() defined?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

After successfull login it redirects to /users/index or /users.

But i didn't set this redirection anywhere.

Where has it been set up ?

How can i change this settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `$this->Auth->loginRedirect`.

Comment: $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'); , this is set in AppController.php but it seems it's not working.